Maximising the difference between the ordering of pairs of elements in a collection of totally ordered sets
Suppose I have $M$ totally ordered sets, all of length $N$, who all share the same elements. For example, for $M=3$ and $N=4$, we can have $S_1 = \{A < B < C < D\}$, $S_2 = \{B < A < C < D\}$, $S_3 = \{D < A < C < B\}$.
Now, suppose we encode the ordering by some antisymmetric matrix (in the i-j indices) $s_{ij}^{\alpha}$; e.g. $s_{12}^{1} \equiv s_{AB}^{S_1} = 1$.
To find how many pairs of orderings differ within a pair of sets, we can then define
$$
\delta(\alpha,\beta) := \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^N |s_{ij}^{\alpha} - s_{ij}^{\beta}|^0
$$
Here, $0 \leq \delta(\alpha,\beta) \leq \frac{N(N-1)}{2}$.
Now, if I have a collection of $M$ such sets, one thing I may want to do is to count the (pairwise) total number of differences between pairs of sets: let
$$
\Delta = \sum_{\alpha=1}^{M-1} \sum_{\beta=\alpha+1}^{M} \delta(\alpha,\beta)
$$
The problem is then bounding this $\Delta$. Of course, the lower bound will be $\min_{s}\Delta = 0$, for which the orderings of elements are all equal across the whole collection of the sets: $S_1 = S_2 = ...$.
The question is: what is $\max_{s} \Delta$? A first try is to maximise $\delta(1,j)$ for all $j\neq1$. Of course, this will fix $\delta(i,j)=0 \forall i\neq 1$, so that $\Delta = (M-1)N(N-1)/2$.
We can instead maximise $\delta(1,j)$ for all even $j$, and minimise it otherwise (i.e. $\delta(3,j)$, $\delta(5,j)$ etc are also all maximised for even $j$, but are all $0$ for odd $j$). For $M=4$ this is already better than the previous case: we get $\Delta = 4N(N-1)/2$ here as opposed to $3N(N-1)/2$ before.
Is this the best way to go about it? We could also think of alternating events : say I take $M=3,N=3$ and alternate $S_1 = \{A<B<C\}$, $S_2 = \{B<C<A\}$, $S_3 = \{C<A<B\}$ where each $\delta$ is $2$, summing up to $\Delta=6$. In this strategy, we get the same $\Delta=6$ as if we took $S_1 = \{A<B<C\}$,$S_2=\{C<B<A\}$,$S_3 = \{A<B<C\}$. If this the right strategy, how would this alternating generalise if $M\neq N$?
In summary, what is the maximum value reached by $\Delta$ for general $M$ and $N$, and in which situations does this occur?
Thank you!

What kind of an answer are you looking for?  An algorithm to comupte the upper bound on $\Delta$?  An asymptotic formula?  Should we treat $M$ or $N$ as fixed and focus on the asymptotic dependence on just one of those variables?

I had as an idea to find the maximum of $\Delta$ for fixed $M$ and $N$, and which strategy to use to get this maximum value (if this strategy is the same for any $M$ and $N$). Rob and subsequent comments seem to indicate the best strategy is indeed to fix one permutation for $M/2$ of the sets and maximise $\delta$ between these and all the others (i.e. alternating orderings of elements). Would be interesting to find a full proof of this :)

Here are the maximum values of $\Delta$ for small $M$ and $N$, obtained via integer linear programming.  They suggest the formula $$\max \Delta = \left\lfloor\frac{M}{2}\right\rfloor \left\lceil\frac{M}{2}\right\rceil \binom{N}{2}.$$
    M\N 1  2  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10 
     1  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0 
     2  0  1  3   6  10  15  21  28  36   45 
     3  0  2  6  12  20  30  42  56  72   90 
     4  0  4 12  24  40  60  84 112 144  180 
     5  0  6 18  36  60  90 126 168 216  270 
     6  0  9 27  54  90 135 189 252 324  405 
     7  0 12 36  72 120 180 252 336 432  540 
     8  0 16 48  96 160 240 336 448 576  720 
     9  0 20 60 120 200 300 420 560 720  900 
    10  0 25 75 150 250 375 525 700 900 1125 


By request, here is the integer linear programming formulation I used.  For $i\in\{1,\dots,M\}$ and $j_1, j_2 \in \{1,\dots,N\}$, let binary decision variable $s_{i j_1 j_2}$ indicate whether set $i$ ranks $j_1$ higher than $j_2$.  The problem is to maximize
$$\Delta = \sum_{1\le i_1<i_2 \le M} \sum_{1\le j_1<j_2 \le N} |s_{i_1 j_1 j_2} - s_{i_2 j_1 j_2}| \tag1\label1$$
subject to
\begin{align}
s_{i j j} &= 0 &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$} \tag2\label2 \\
s_{i j_1 j_2} + s_{i j_2 j_1} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$ and $j_1 < j_2$} \tag3\label3
\end{align}
To linearize the objective \eqref{1}, introduce binary decision variable $d_{i_1 i_2 j_1 j_2}$ to represent $|s_{i_1 j_1 j_2} - s_{i_2 j_1 j_2}|$, and maximize
$$\Delta = \sum_{1\le i_1<i_2 \le M} \sum_{1\le j_1<j_2 \le N} d_{i_1 i_2 j_1 j_2} \tag4\label4$$
subject to \eqref{2}, \eqref{3}, and
$$
d_{i_1 i_2 j_1 j_2} \le s_{i_1 j_1 j_2} + s_{i_2 j_2 j_1} \le 2 - d_{i_1 i_2 j_1 j_2} \quad \text{for $i_1 < i_2$ and $j_1 < j_2$} \tag5\label5
$$
The idea is that \eqref{5} enforces the logical implication
$$d_{i_1 i_2 j_1 j_2} = 1 \implies s_{i_1 j_1 j_2} + s_{i_2 j_2 j_1} = 1,$$
equivalently (because $s$ is binary),
$$d_{i_1 i_2 j_1 j_2} = 1 \implies s_{i_1 j_1 j_2} \not= s_{i_2 j_2 j_1},$$
equivalently (because $s$ is binary),
$$d_{i_1 i_2 j_1 j_2} = 1 \implies |s_{i_1 j_1 j_2} - s_{i_2 j_2 j_1}| = 1.$$

Trivial but possibly useful observation: the conjectured value is achieved by taking $\lfloor M/2\rfloor$ of the orderings to be some $\pi$, and the rest to be the reverse of $\pi$.

Could you write the integer program? That itself would be valuable, and certainly its not obvious to me.

@stochasticboy321 I added an ILP formulation to my answer.

Thanks! I did not think to make the $s_{i,j_1,j_2}$ the decision variables, that's pretty clever!

Thank you, that's very helpful!
